# Reactjs material-UI TextField apply css properties

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a similar [login page](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/sign-in/) made with material-UI but in my code there are differences with original one. Actually, the problem is starting when I click on the TextField.
The old inputs will shown and I select one of them the background of TextField become white.
In addition, if there are passwords saved on chrome when entering the login page for the first time, it automatically makes the background white by auto-filling.
My login page theme is dark and it is looking bad. How can I make textField background same with Material-UI login page?

Here is my code part:

```
const CssTextField = withStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
      borderBottomColor: 'yellow',
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '& fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'white',
      },
      '&:hover fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'white',
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'yellow',
      },'&.Mui-focused ': {
        
      },
    },
  },
})(TextField);

export default function SignIn(props) {


  return (
 <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <CssTextField
            focused={true}
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="userName"
            name="text"
            type="text" 
            {...username}
            autoComplete="text"
            autoFocus
            InputLabelProps={{
              style: { color: '#fff' },
            }}
            InputProps={{
              style: {
                  color: "red"
              }
          }}
          
          />
    </form>
)


}
```

It is look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
const styles = { WebkitBoxShadow: "0 0 0 1000px white inset" };
<CssTextField inputProps={{ style: inputStyle }} />
```

Keep in mind, that in material-ui there is a difference between inputProps and InputProps. The capital I changes the component, that is wrapped around the native input and the lowercase i manipulates the native input.